# Javascript function inside php, does not work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a webpage which displays rows from a database inside text boxes.  I have made buttons one of which when clicked dynamically creates a row with input boxes.  So this `onClick` function written with javascript to create these boxes is not being triggered.  The error thrown out by the concole is `addInput() not defined`.

```
<?php
    include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');

    echo '    <h1>\n' .
         '        Revenue Management Solution\n' .
         '    </h1>\n';

    echo '    <img alt   = "mxpresso logo"\n' .
         '         src   = "http://mxpresso.com/images/logo.png"\n' .
         '         style = "width : 171px; height : 108px;">\n\n';

    echo '    <h2>\n' .
         '        1. To See existing records\n' .
         '    </h2>\n';

    $db = NewADOConnection( 'mysql' );

    $db -> Connect( "127.0.0.1",
                    "vcc",
                    "abcd4",
                    "vcc" );

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rev";

    $result = $db->Execute( $sql );

    if ( $result === false )
        die( "failed2" );

    $records = array();

    $count = $result -> RecordCount();
    echo "Total Records Found :".$count."<br>";

    if ( $count > 0 )
    {
        while ( !$result -> EOF )
        {
            $offerId   = $result -> fields[ 0 ];
            $affId     = $result -> fields[ 1 ];
            $status    = $result -> fields[ 2 ];
            $deduction = $result -> fields[ 3 ];

            echo '    <form action = "updatecopy.php"\n' .
                 '          method = "get"\n' .
                 '          target = "_blank">\n' .
                 '        <div id = "dynamicInput">\n' .
                 '            <table id    = "dataTable"\n' .
                 '                   class = "form">\n' .
                 '                <tbody>\n' .
                 '                    <tr>\n' .
                 '                        <td>\n' .
                 '                            <input checked  = "checked"\n' .
                 '                                   required = "required"\n' .
                 '                                   name     = "chk[]"\n' .
                 '                                   type     = "checkbox">\n' .
                 '                        </td>\n\n';

            echo '                        <td>\n' .
                 '                            <h4>\n' .
                 '                                OfferID\n' .
                 '                            </h4>\n\n';

            echo '                            <input name  = "update_for_offerid"\n' .
                 '                                   type  = "text"\n' .
                 '                                   value = ' .
                     $offerId .
                     '>\n' .
                 '                        </td>\n\n';

            echo '                        <td>\n' .
                 '                            <h4>\n' .
                 '                                AffId\n' .
                 '                            </h4>\n\n';

            echo '                            <input name  = "update_for_affid"\n' .
                 '                                   type  = "text"\n' .
                 '                                   value = ' .
                     $affId .
                     '>\n' .
                 '                        </td>\n\n';

            echo '                        <td>\n' .
                 '                            <h4>\n' .
                 '                                deduction :\n' .
                 '                            </h4>\n\n';

            echo '                            <input name  = "deduct"\n' .
                 '                                   type  = "text"
                 '                                   value = ' .
                     $deduction .
                     '>\n' .
                 '                        </td>\n\n';

            echo '                        <td>\n' .
                 '                            <h4>\n' .
                 '                                Status\n' .
                 '                            </h4>\n\n';

            echo '                            <input name  = "status"\n' .
                 '                                   type  = "text" ' .
                 '                                   value = ' .
                     $status .
                     '>\n' .
                 '                        </td>\n' .
                 '                    </tr>\n' .
                 '                </tbody>\n' .
                 '            </table>\n\n';

            echo '            <input type  = "submit"\n' .
                 '                   value = "Update Entry">\n' .
                 '        </div>\n' .
                 '    </form>\n\n';

            $rec = array( "offerId"      => $offerId,
                          "affiliate_id" => $affId,
                          "status"       => $status,
                          "deduction"    => $deduction );

            array_push( $records,
                        $rec );

            $result->MoveNext();
        }
    }

    echo '    <input type    = "button"\n' .
         '           onClick = "addInput(\'dynamicInput\')"\n' .
         '           value   = "Add another text input">\n\n';

    echo '    <script language = "Javascript"\n' .
         '            type     = "javascript">\n' .
         '        var counter = 1;\n' .
         '        var limit   = 3;\n\n';

    echo '        function addInput( divName )\n' .
         '        {\n' .
         '            if ( counter == limit )\n' .
         '            {\n' .
         '                alert( "You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs" );\n' .
         '        }\n' .
         '        else\n' .
         '        {\n' .
         '            var newtable = document.createElement( "dataTable1" );\n' .
         '            var td1 = document.createElement(\'td\');\n' .
         '            var td2 = document.createElement(\'td\');\n' .
         '            var td3 = document.createElement(\'td\');\n'
         '            var tr = document.createElement( \'tr\' );\n\n';

    echo '            td1.innerHTML = \'<h4>Entry</h4>\' + \'<br><input name = "myI" type = "text">\';\n\n';

    echo '            td2.innerHTML = \'<h4>Entry</h4>\' + \'<br><input name = "myI" type = "text">\';\n\n';

    echo '            td3.innerHTML = \'<h4>Entry</h4> \' + \'<br><input name = "myIn" type = "text">\';\n\n';

    echo '            tr.appendChild( td1 );\n' .
         '            tr.appendChild( td2 );\n' .
         '            tr.appendChild( td3 );\n\n';

    echo '            newtable.appendChild( tr );\n\n';

    echo '            document.getElementById( divName ).appendChild( newtable );\n\n';

    echo '            counter++;\n' .
         '        }\n' .
         '    </script>\n';
?>
```

Comment: Don't **bold everything**. Also you should re-think your strategy. Layering HTML inside JavaScript inside HTML inside PHP is not the best plan. Remember, instead of a long-winded `echo` you can just close out your `<?php` tag and go back to echo-by-default mode.

Comment: @tadman how should i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm too noob to comment, and while this isn't a complete answer, I believe it will send you along your way well enough.  If you were to get this page delivered to you in a browser, then "inspect" using the debug tool of your favorite browser, you would likely find that the javascript isn't registered with the browser as a "script" source, but rather just text inside the  element that's not displaying cause DOM rules.  This of course makes it non-executable, as you would be able to tell since the event isn't firing.  addInput() not defined since it's inside a script that's not registered.

This is kind of tricky layering it like this. FWIW, my solution to this kind of thing was to declare a JS script in the caller  -> that had a function that created a new page (using JS of course), >that .append 'ed all the elements to the defined script, the "source" of the script being a separate JS file.  This also allows me to use the IDE to maintain the script in a separate file.

There are several ways to "post" the script as an element, but it needs to be posted to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `>`:

```
echo '<html
```

Comment: the html tags are not really required if i echo my html/js code. Can you check if the problem is somwhere calling or inside the function

Answer (score 0):

javascript is case sensive, it should be onclick not onClick.
I din't really got deeper in your code, but if this doesn't solve it then tell me

Comment: No this did not

Comment: my javascript does work, when i executed it in just a simple html code. By the problem is using it with php

Comment: I suppose that /select shouldn't be there? I'm putting your code to test and I'll see what I get

Comment: please do it and let me know

Comment: btw - why are all echo's outside of html / body? can you add result of ctrl+u to your post?

Comment: Because the html is inside a php code if you notice, so the echo of php is being used execute html. Otherwise how would i do it. An dmorover the html and body tags are not really rquired when i use echo.